# gitlab 8.2.1, How to use cache in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use 'cache' in .gitlab-ci.yml (http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache). My gitlab version is 8.2.1 and my Runner is:

```
$ docker exec -it gitlab-runner gitlab-runner -v 
gitlab-runner version 0.7.2 (998cf5d)
```

So according to the doc, everything is up to date, but I'm unable to use the cache ;-(. All my files are always deleted. Am I doing something wrong?

A cache archive is created, but not passed to the next jobs.

## Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
$ cat .gitlab-ci.yml
    stages:
    - createcache
    - testcache

    createcache:
      type: createcache
      cache:
        untracked: true
        paths:
          - doc/
      script:
        - touch doc/cache.txt

    testcache:
      type: testcache
      cache:
        untracked: true
        paths:
          - doc/
      script:
        - find .
        - ls doc/cache.txt
```

## Output of the job 'createcache'

```
Running on runner-141d90d4-project-2-concurrent-0 via 849d416b5994...
Fetching changes...
HEAD is now at 2ffbadb MUST BE REVERTED
[...]
$ touch doc/cache.txt
[...]
Archiving cache...
INFO[0000] Creating archive cache.tgz ...              
INFO[0000] Done!                                        

Build succeeded.
```

## Output of the job 'testcache'

```
Running on runner-141d90d4-project-2-concurrent-0 via 849d416b5994...
Fetching changes...
Removing doc/cache.txt
[...]
$ ls doc/cache.txt
ls: cannot access doc/cache.txt: No such file or directory

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 1
```

## My workaround

My workaround is to manually untar what's in the /cache directory ... I'm pretty sure that's not the correct way to use cache ...

```
$ cat .gitlab-ci.yml
    stages:
    - build
    - test
    - deploy

    image: ubuntu:latest

    before_script:
      - export CACHE_FILE=`echo ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/createcache/${CI_BUILD_REF_NAME}/cache.tgz | sed -e "s|/builds|/cache|"`

    createcache:
      type: build
      cache:
        untracked: true
        paths:
          - doc/
      script:
        - find . | grep -v ".git"
        - mkdir -p doc
        - touch doc/cache.txt

    testcache:
      type: test
      script:
        - env
        - find . | grep -v ".git"
        - tar xvzf ${CACHE_FILE}
        - ls doc/cache.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps this is due to how you reduced, but please heed "Don’t mix the caching with passing artifacts between stages. Caching is not designed to pass artifacts between stages." https://docs.gitlab.com/ee//ci/caching/index.html#cache-vs-artifacts

Answer (score 14, accepted):

8.2 only supports per-job cache, and 8.3 will introduce "group" cache that serves among jobs according to [@ayufan's comment in Possibility to cache folders in build directory (#97)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/97#note_2812556).

<s>However, although I cannot be 100% sure, by quick digging the source code of gitlab-ci-muti-runner, docker executor doesn't seems to work with the cache functionality. Since a whole new container is created and destroyed in every job, the cache.tgz archive would no longer exist in the next build.</s>

**Errata:**

*The above description is incorrect* due to testing in a misconfigured environment. By default, gitlab-ci-multi-runner creates a dedicated data volume container as a cache storage for each concurrent build. The cache container is mounted to directory `/cache` in the application container and those cache.tgz tarballs are placed under `/cache` by default. So caches are actually reusable among independent builds.

**Updates 2015/12/11:**

Just found out that "group" cache has already been implemented in [gitlab-runner@7dc9524f6ef0144b3797fc07c9035f38a8ad0512](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/commit/7dc9524f6ef0144b3797fc07c9035f38a8ad0512), maybe not yet released and documented. You can enable it with

```
cache:
  paths:
    - doc/
  group: sharedcache
```

The result is one cache tarball being placed under path `<namespace>/<repo>/sharedcache/` instead of two cache tarballs being placed separately under path `<namespace>/<repo>/createcache/` and `<namespace>/<repo>/testcache/`.

**Updates 2017/12/04:**

"group" cache has been replaced by `cache:key`. Use the `key` key to make the cache share between jobs or git references. By default, a cache is shared between all jobs. So, simply write the following would do the job

```
cache:
  paths:
    - doc/
```

Checkout [GitLab CI cache:key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache) and [gitlab-runner@d34f76f86a7c2fc4d399e9922175bcc614434016](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/commit/d34f76f86a7c2fc4d399e9922175bcc614434016) for more information.

Comment: CI linter says `test:cache config contains unknown keys: group`

Comment: @Kyslik It has been replaced by `cache:key`. Check out https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/commit/d34f76f86a7c2fc4d399e9922175bcc614434016 and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache-key

Comment: Just a comment - it's *much* easier to read your answer if you finish each edit with a complete answer. There is an edit history, so we can see what you've changed. There's no need for headings for edits; just update the content so it reads clearly.

Answer (score 25):

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/327

```
image: java:openjdk-8-jdk

before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - ./gradlew assemble

test:
  stage: test
  script:
     - ./gradlew check
```

Comment: I used the config above but the gradle wrapper was still downloading the files into .gradle/wrapper. Maybe it's some other related issue.

Comment: I have to say I have seen the same results as @SailAvid. I also attempted to cache about every possible gradle directory that could exist from the first job (e.g. build) and all dependencies were getting pulled again in the second job.

Comment: Same here. When reading the file, it looks like we're setting `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to a path *inside* the build-folder (so we can cache it) and the cache seems to be created and applied on following jobs but gradle keeps downloading. Any new ideas on this?

Comment: Same happens to me, it saves the cache and applies it but Gradle is still downloading, any news on this?

Answer (score 4):

It seems it is not possible to cache container local files with shared runners. You have to put your files in e.g. the cache folder:

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/cache/.gradle

...

cache:
  paths:
    - $GRADLE_USER_HOME/caches/
    - $GRADLE_USER_HOME/wrapper/
    - $GRADLE_USER_HOME/build-cache/
```

Strictly it is not required to put the /cache folder as files to cache, because this happens automatically, but I leave it for clarity (also when I want to move the gradle cache)

Comment: Is the `/cache` documented somewhere? I've only seen docs mentioning [cache:](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#cache)

Comment: I remember it reading it somewhere, maybe they changed the behavior and/or removed it from the docs?

Answer (score 0):

We found out, that is better to cache the whole `.gradle`-folder. This should be used only once per project. If k8s used for gitlab-runner, then you should turn the daemon off.

`gitlab-ci.yaml`:

```
variables:
  GRADLE_OPTS: "-Dorg.gradle.daemon=false" # no gradle-daemon on k8s

# ...

buildJar:
  stage: build
  image: gradle:5.6.4-jdk11
  before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
  script:
    - gradle assemble
  cache:
    key: "gradleCache"
    paths:
      - .gradle
```