# gitlab ci always downloads dependencies - cache in runners isn't working

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new to gitlab CI and trying to build my maven project using gitlab.
I created my own docker image for builds and I am using my local runner.
My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks as below: **Edited:**

```
image: registry.gitlab.com/girishenoy2003/docker-java-8-mvn-3.6.3:latest
services:
  - docker:dind
stages:
  - compile
  - test
before_script:
  - export MVN_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.m2
cache:
  paths:
    - $MVN_USER_HOME/.m2/repository/
    - target/
maven-compile:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - mvn compile
  tags:
    - my-local-runner
  only:
    - master
maven-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn test
  tags:
    - my-local-runner
  only:
    - master
```

During the compile stage I expect all the dependencies to download and cache it and while running test I expect it to get it from cache as I am using my local runner for both jobs.

How can we avoid download of dependent jars from downloading in different jobs?

**P.S.:**

- I already looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162120/gitlab-ci-gradle-dependency-cache) - but didn't help
- I know that if I use `mvn test-compile` it will do the trick but I wanted to make it in different jobs to segregate the stages

Edit:
Some runner logs:

```
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/aws-learning-path/spring-boot-rest/.git/
Checking out f86f9c63 as master...
Removing "..\\..\\..\\cache\\aws-learning-path\\spring-boot-rest\\default\\cache.zip"
Removing target/
Skipping Git submodules setup
Restoring cache
00:00
Checking cache for default...
No URL provided, cache will not be downloaded from shared cache server. Instead a local version of cache will be extracted. 
Successfully extracted cache
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
$ export MVN_USER_HOME=/root
$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.2.RELEASE.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.2.2.RELEASE.pom (8.1 kB at 3.3 kB/s)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, in my case variable's value was visible only in `script` block, not in `cache`. So first value of `cache:paths` is `/.m2/repository/` - from root.
I moved my variable to the `variables` block.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is related to your /root folder

The gitlab-runner do not cache any paths outside of project directory, you need to configure your CI to download and store the dependencies inside your project path

Comment: I changed the HOME variable - edited the original post, but no luck.
It still downloads everything in each stage

Comment: The problem is not related to your home directory...you need to move the dependencies to inside your project pah.