# Gitlab CI + maven: Use another repo as local dependency

Tags: java, git, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I started using gitlab for CI with maven.
I'de like to use another gitlab repo as a dependency for my project but i have no clue on how to do it.

My current .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: maven:3-jdk-8
variables:
   MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2

build:
  script: "mvn clean install"
  artifacts:
    name: "oslib"
    paths:
    - "target/*.jar"
```

Comment: There is a feature request for this here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/14728 The issue contains some ideas on how to workaround it.

Comment: This probably answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462371/gitlabs-artifact-of-one-project-used-in-further-projects